# Nodejs post empty object

Tags: node.js, ajax

I simply make a ajax call to certain method in nodeJs app, and expected to log all parameters to see pass data properly. but since I post this its not..

```
 var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// set the port of our application
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// make express look in the public directory for assets (css/js/img)
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.get('/', function(req, res) {

    // ejs render automatically looks in the views folder
    res.render('index');
});

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Our app is running on http://localhost:' + port);
});

'use strict';

app.post('/sendMail', function(request, response) {
    console.log(request.body)//returns {}  but why its empty? 
})
```

and here is ajax call;(I validate paramters exist in headers via dev console)

```
constructor() {
      this.message={
          email:"",
          message:""
      }
  }

  @action postData() {
    $.ajax({
  url:"http://localhost:8080/sendMail",
  ContentType:'application/json',
  dataType:'json',
  type:'post',
  data:{body:this.message},
  success:(result) =>{
  },
```

EDITED: I am able to see data in log if I make a post request via POSTMAN I choose content-type:application/json and added raw json string "{'message':'hello world'}" and I saw in nodejs log its passed successfully whats wrong with my ajax call here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's empty because your using specifying the request should contain a JSON body but don't actually send JSON, your sending an object.

In your ajax request, Change this line

```
data:{body:this.message}
```

to

```
data: JSON.stringify(this.message)
```

Comment: @TyForHelpDude Can you inspect the request coming from the client and post the results?